# Angular 8 cannot get child panel to scroll properly to top of screen

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scrollbar

I have a parent component that has 4 child components inside of it, each of them a primeNg panel with a form inside of them.  The first 3 panels are expanded at all times(the collapse and expand icons are set to empty strings) and the last one is collapsed on load. On the last panel, I have a button that allows you to "Edit" the information which appears inside it and expands the panel.

What I would like is for this 4th panel to then get pulled to the top of the screen. However what actually happens is the panel expands and the scroll bar moves up, but the panel itself stays put.

I have tried several different options to get this working using various combinations of scrollTop, offsetTop, scrollIntoView, etc but nothing has worked.  The scrollbar moves but the content does not, it stays where it was.

I even tried to set the id to an element half way down the form on the last panel and then used scrollIntoView: {block: 'center'} as an option...still nothing, same thing, it scrolls the scrollbar but not the content.

Can someone help me out with this and let me know what I am doing wrong?

in parent component:

```
<p-panel1></p-panel1>
<p-panel2></p-panel2>
<p-panel3></p-panel3>
<p-panel4 id='scrollToHere'></p-panel4> <---I want to scroll p-panel4 to top of the window 
                                            when the edit button is clicked
```

UPDATE:
Got it fixed by using `setTimeout(document.getElementById('scrollToHere').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'}),0)`

gotta be one of those weird DOM things where it tried to scroll before the panel was expanded...will try and change it to onAfterToggle but not sure if that will work because I am not using the icons and using a button to do it.

Comment: Could you post the relevant section of your code?

Comment: @SimonCrane there isn't a lot I can really post, but I posted the general setup of the parent component HTML...basically I want to scroll p-panel4 to the top of the window when it gets expanded. I've also tried putting the 'scrollToHere' id on an element inside p-panel4 about half way down but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Matte the scroll into view should work.  But it seems that the scroll into view is triggered before you contents are expanded  so try with some delay. And there should be more page content below your last panel if there is nothing and it is the last thing on page then the page would not scroll to the top of the height is smaller then the screen

Comment: Yes, I found this out on my own after remembering a similar issue I had a while back on another project...even using setTimeout(0) works...but you definitely deserve the credit for solving it out of the box without having to go through all of it haha

Comment: also found out that onAfterToggle works too, although it scrolls past the panel header